# Sage CRM - It is possible to create secondary teams?

Tags: crm, administration, sage-crm

For example I have a primary team called "Cable Management" and i want to create secondary teams IC1 and IC2 that are children of Cable Management, and then to those IC1 and IC2 secondary teams, add some users.

How can i achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: Hey Gianni, what do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I wanto to create some custom calendar in a .asp page in which the html table headers are shown like: the row one will be the  "Cable Management" team with colspan = 2 and then the second row will be the IC1 and IC2 (copy paste this in note pad i think `' Cable Management '
' IC1    ' IC2     '
' DATA   ' DATA    '
'        ' DATA    '
' DATA   '         '`) Doubt is how do i represent this in Sage CRM (I want to build the html table by reading the data from the DDBB; like the primary teams, its children etc) and of course when creating a new appointment be able to select a group of users

Comment: I see that with Zones can create child zones and etc and i can add the field comm_secterr to the CommunicationSchedulingBox screen, but zones are more focused to territory right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this using teams, then you can add a new field to the Team entity. Team is listed under Administration > Customisation > Secondary Entities > Team.

Add a field of type "Team Select" and give it a Column Name, Caption, etc. We would advise something like "Parent Team" (chan_parentchannelid).

Next, edit the team screens to include your new field. The screens you probably want to edit are:
 - Team Search Box (ChannelSearchBox)
 - Team Admin Box (ChannelAdminBoxLong)

Once you have added the field to those screens, you can start to specify parent teams in the system. This will record a link from one team to another. You can then use this link in the database to select parent details.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    t.chan_channelid AS teamid
    , t.chan_description AS teamdescription
    , p.chan_channelid AS parentid
    , p.chan_description AS parentdescription
FROM channel AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN channel AS p on p.chan_deleted IS NULL
    AND p.chan_channelid = t.chan_parentchannelid
WHERE t.chan_deleted IS NULL
```

Please note: The above SQL is untested :)

You can essentially create as many child Teams as you want using this method, each with their own child Teams.

You may also want to add the new Parent field to the Team list (ChannelAdminGrid).

We hope that helps!
Six Ticks Support

Comment: Wow thanks! I now see the teams in the select when creating an appointment and through .asp and sql can see the relationship :)

Comment: Great! Glad we could help :)